# Postman/ElasticSearch: Difference between results of curl vs one sent via postman

Tags: http, elasticsearch, postman

Following query does not return correct data when fired from POSTMAN.
The intention to get only that search data that contains host == host-2

```
POST - {{SERVER}}/elasticsearch/{{INDEX}}/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "host:host-2",
        "analyze_wildcard": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While the curl command works perfectly fine:

```
curl -k -XPOST 'https://{{SERVER}}/elasticsearch/{{INDEX}}/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "host:host-2",
        "analyze_wildcard": true
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Also, the following call returns correct results from POSTMAN !!:

```
{{SERVER}}/elasticsearch/{{INDEX}}/_search?q=host:host-2
```

Is this because of the **'-d'** sent via **curl** which wasn't sent via **POSTMAN**? Is there some other **http format** required to be sent from **POSTMAN**?

Comment: Can you add an HTTP request header `Content-Type: application/json` and see if it helps?

Comment: Besides your query is malformed, you have one too many `query` it seems.

Comment: Thanks @Val - this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - so following works (prefixing the server call with **HTTPS://**). Surprisingly, when i remove the ***https***, it gives me back the results of GET call instead of POST !?

```
POST - https://{{SERVER}}/elasticsearch/{{INDEX}}/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "host:host-2",
        "analyze_wildcard": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks @Val